# ruby: finish loop iteration before raising Interrupt

Tags: ruby, loops, exception, error-handling, interrupt

I'm looping through a lot of items and I want to periodically interrupt the loop to save and continue at a later time like this:

```
begin
  big_list.each do |i|
    # sensitive stuff
    sensitive_method(i)
    # other sensitive stuff
  end
rescue Interrupt
  # finish the current iteration
  # then do something else (save)
  # don't raise (print done)
end
```

By sensitive I mean that, if `Interrupt` is raised in the middle of an iteration, data will be corrupted so I need to guarantee that the iteration finishes before exiting.

Also, if another exception is raised, it should still finish the loop but raise it afterwards

### EDIT:

Using the answer by mudasobwa in a test scenario:

```
while true
  result = begin
             puts "start"
             sleep 1
             puts "halfway"
             sleep 1
             puts "done\n\n"
              nil
            rescue Exception => e
              e
            end
  case result
    when Interrupt
      puts "STOPPED"
      break
    when Exception then raise result
  end
end
```

I get:

```
start
halfway
done

start
^C: /...
STOPPED
```

which is my exact problem, I need it to finish the loop (sleep, print halfway, sleep, print done) and only then break out (wrapping the puts, sleep... in a method does not help)

Comment: you can move `begin..rescue` inside loop

Comment: you should rescue `Interrupt` inside `sensitive_method` otherwise you'll have to restart/recall that method invocation when you rescue it outside of the loop.  Then raise a shutdown error/method from within `sensitive_method` (assuming everything is synchronous).

Comment: @Anthony ok, but won't the method body also stop executing half-way if I interrupt, that's what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** There is no way to continue the execution of the method from inside the middle of it.

```
big_list.each do |i|
  # sensitive stuff
  result = begin
             sensitive_method(i)
             nil
           rescue Exception => e
             e
           end
  # other sensitive stuff
  case result
    when Interrupt
      puts "done"
      break "done"
    when Exception then raise result
  end
end
```

*Sidenote:* you probably don’t want to rescue the topmost `Exception`, but some subclass that makes sense to rescue.

---

To make it possible to finish the chunk of operations:

```
operations = [
  -> { puts "start" },
  -> { sleep 1 },
  -> { puts "halfway" },
  -> { sleep 1 },
  -> { puts "done\n\n" }
]

def safe_chunk(operations, index = 0)
  result = operations[index..-1].each_with_index(index) do |op, idx|
    begin
      op.()
    rescue Exception => e
      safe_chunk(operations, idx) # or idx + 1
      break e
    end
  end
  result.is_a?(Array) ? nil : result
end
```

Comment: The sensitive method above means an atomic operation. If you want to be able to finish many operations, you should break the `sensitive_method` into _atomic_ operations, and manually re-run the chunk. See an update.

Answer (score 2):

The Interrupt exception is raised in the main thread.  If you use a worker thread to process the list it will never be interrupted. You will need a way to tell the worker thread to terminate though.  Rescuing Interrupt in the main thread and setting a flag that's checked by the child can accomplish this.

```rb
BigList = (1..100)

def sensitive_method(item)
  puts "start #{item}"
  sleep 1
  puts "halfway #{item}"
  sleep 1
  puts "done #{item}"
  puts
end

@done = false

thread = Thread.new do
  begin
    BigList.each do |item|
      break if @done
      sensitive_method item
    end
  end
end

begin
  thread.join
rescue Interrupt
  @done = true
  thread.join
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `ensure`, used in rescue clauses, is available for situation such as this one, where code must be executed after an exception occurs.

```
[-1, 0, 1].each do |i|
  begin
    puts "i=#{i} before exception"
    # <additional code>  
    n = 1/i
  rescue ZeroDivisionError => e
    puts "Exception: #{e}"
    exit
  ensure
    puts "Just executed 1/#{i}"
    # <additional code>  
  end
end

i=-1 before exception
Just executed 1/-1
i=0 before exception
Exception: divided by 0
Just executed 1/0
```

Notice that `begin/rescue/ensure/end` must be inside the loop and that the code after `ensure` is executed for each `i` regardless of whether a zero-divide exception occurs.